# How to get to sentence in cxx file when with debug mode in the Scintilla project

Tags: debugging, mfc, scintilla

I had a trouble about the scintilla ,I want to fix it with debug mode, But,How can I trace into the cxx file?f10 in vs does not work....

Answer (score 0):

F11 is normally step-into. F10 will step-over. As long as you have the scintilla debug symbols it'll work without problems.